Building an inflatable sphere
This is seemingly an easy problem, but in practice it is far beyond my grasp. How to build an inflatable sphere (or ellipsoid) from two planar surfaces bound together? I'd like to create a balloon with an ellipsoid shape from cutting two sheets of plastic and sealing them together. What is the optimal planar shape to approximate a sphere?
Picture the typical mylar balloon: it is offered commercially in many shapes, but lots of wrinkles appear. It makes sense since it is generated from just a planar shape, which does not have any Gaussian curvature and will not have it when inflated. Your typical rubber balloon is in fact not planar when deflated, but has an interesting concave shape which turns ellipsoidal when inflated.


It is also hard for a balloon to deviate too much from their initial planar shape by creating, say, a sphere; it is at best blown a bit in the middle. Doing a bit of numerical integration (I can provide my messy code) I have obtained this shape below, which is supposed to have the same area as 1/4 of an ellipsoid. But when cut, sealed and inflated it does not approximate an ellipsoid at all: too "peaky" and not round enough. To say nothing about the wrinkles. I am assuming that the same technique can be used for a sphere, and then stretched a bit in one dimension generating an ellipsoid (or spheroid).


I have read a few papers about inflatable shapes, but none provide an answer to this seemingly easy question: what planar shape generates a sphere when inflated, or at least as close as possible? Some additional questions for extra points:

How can this shape be computed?
What is the deviation?
Can it be stretched to an ellipsoid?
Can it be generalized to generic 3d shapes?

Note: commercial ventures create good-enough
spheres by joining together several segments instead of just two. This is quite easier and not what is asked here.


I have been investigating a bit about commercial spherical balloons online, and it appears that it is impossible to get a round spherical balloon just with two planar surfaces. The best approximation would be, by symmetry, just a couple of circles sealed together, and they seem to create just your typical round oblate (pancake) spheroid. With four segments you can already have a good spherical approximation, and quality spheres are made of eight or more segments. No idea as to why, though; would be great to have an explanation.

To confirm, you're asking about effectively non-elastic material (mylar, not latex), right? <> Qualitatively, assuming non-elastic material, the total Gaussian curvature $4\pi$ has to be "distributed" over the boundary curves of planar pieces. For flat pieces lying in a plane and attached along common boundaries (like two disks joined edge to edge), the curvature along the boundary is a "1-dimensional density": infinite at each point, but the integral over a boundary arc is finite. Structures made from gores can be more spherical because they have longer total boundary.

Yes, exactly, non-elastic material.

Please refer to the article called Profiles of inflated surfaces.

It's been an interesting trip. The answer is in the excellent paper The Mylar Balloon Revisited, by Ivaïlo M. Mladenov and John Oprea. I found it as a reference in the rather more obscure Profiles of inflated surfaces, by Igor Pak and Jean-Marc Schlenker, sent by Ng Chung Tak in a comment above (thanks!).
In short, the answer is that an inflated Mylar balloon from two joint circles creates an oblate shape (but not quite an ellipsoid), with ratio ~0.6 between its thickness and its diameter. The paper contains a full parametrization of this shape.
So a proper sphere cannot be even approximated by two planar figures joint and inflated. It should be doable however with 4 or more planar figures joint and inflated.
